# TDD: How to write unit tests when method depends on network URL's

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I try to write method which consumes some url address, and returns resources (RSS feeds for instance).

```
public class NewsSourcesService {

    public List<News> getNewsSource(String url) {

    }

}
```

I plan to use ROME internally, but it shouldn't be visible by dependencies.
It's difficult to write unit test for that method, because preparing fake state is impossible and there is nothing to mock.

What is the best approach for writing tests in such cases?

Comment: The question is: what do you want to test? That a request is made at an endpoint?

Comment: Why is preparing fake state impossible?

Comment: @Tunaki That different variants of RSS/ATOMS resources are consumed correctly.

Comment: @erip Ok it's not easy. The only idea for me is to prepare fake RSS resource as file. But testing state instead of behaviors is not good.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to start with **component test** of a new functionality. Component test means a test of service (in SOA terms) together with it's adapter (shell script, http resource, gui etc.), treated as a black box (you have no idea what is inside, you know only entry interface and external services that it depends on).

In your service signature we see that you want to get a list of RSS News from given rss url. Let's assume that an adapter for that service is a simple http controller.

I will use pseudo code here since I am not a java native ;)

```
function testThatListOfRSSNewsCanBeRetrieved() {
    expectedNews = [
         new News.with(new Title('Test title.')).with(new Content('Test content.')).build(),
         new News.with(new Title('Test title 2.')).with(new Content('Test content 2.')).build()
    ];
    rssFeed.addNews(expectedNews);

    retrievedNews = applicationRunner.getRSSNews();
    assertThat(retrievedNews, areSameAs(expectedNews))
}
```

Ok, that was easy. As you can see test is clear and easy to understand (I hope).

#### First we create expected news list using builder pattern.

Notice that You don't have to do that. You can simply use domain value object here directly. I like to use builders because when constructor of a given value object changes, then I don't have to change that in all of my tests, only in builder.

#### In the second part we add newses using `rssFeed` instance.

`rssFeed` is an object that controls mocked external rss server. We have to launch that server before our tests. It simply serves what we tell it to serve. By calling `addNews` we tell it to serve given list of newses when requested. There are libraries for such fake servers. With this approach we are not coupling our service implementation with tests, because even if implementation changes, tests should still work.

#### Then we run our application and check if it works as we meant.

To run application we use wrapper object `applicationRunner` which should run app in separate process (start http server in this example), make a request to it, create newses from response and return these.
Lastly we assert that retrieved newses are the same that we prepared earlier.

That's all for component test. Keep in my mind that you shouldn't create too many such tests, cause' they are slow. Usually one, max two, are enough to cover one feature.

**This is not the end!**

Now coming from your component test you can plan service implementation and make unit/integration tests for it.

What we want our service to do is return a list of RSS newses from given url, and this is our top responsibility which will be implemented in service layer. Let's write a test for that:

```
function testThatNewsListCanBeRetrieved() {
    rssURL = 'http://megarss.com';
    expectedNews = [new News.build()];
    mockedRSSDataRetrieve = mock(RSSDataRetrieve());
    mockedRSSDataRetrieve.on('get').withParameters(rssURL).returnValue(expectedNews);
    service = new RSSNewsRetrieve(mockedRSSDataRetrieve);

    newsList = service.newsList();
    assertThat(newsList, areSameAs(expectedNews));
}
```

By writing implementation to this test we can distill two new responsibilities (notice that we can discover new responsibilites during implementation, which often happens and it's nothing wrong):

- RSS data retrieve (gateway to external RSS service):

  Gateway object that makes request to given url and returns raw RSS data.
- RSS response parse:

  Gets raw RSS data and returns our News objects.

To test service `RSSNewsRetrieve` we had to mock out `RSSDataRetrieve`, because we don't want to call external service in unit tests (unit tests should run in isolation and quickly). `RSSResponseParse` doesn't have to be mocked or even injected since it has no dependancies that keeps us from running in isolation.

Now we can write unit test for `RSSResponseParser` which I won't cover here since it'simple.

What is left to test is `RSSDataRetrieve`. We will test it using integration test.

Integration tests doesn't need to run in isolation and can be a bit slower than unit tests. Because we don't want to couple our test to implementation and keep it deterministic we can again use our fake RSS server created for component test.

```
function testThatRSSDataCanBeRetrieved() {
    expectedNews = [new News.build()];
    rssFeed.addNews(expectedNews);

    rssDataRetrieve = new RSSDataRetrieve();
    rssData = rssDataRetrieve.get(this.url); // this url is passed to rssFeed on initialization
    assertThat(rssData, isTheSameAs(newsToRawRSSData(expectedNews));
}
```

I didn't write unit test for service HTTP adapter becuase it's covered by component test.

With this set of tests we have covered basisc of functionality keeping readability and maintainability at high level.

Of course now you can add more tests for different cases, in example how application should behave if RSS server is unavailable or if RSS server returns data in wrong format.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The common technique to use is "dependency injection" where your class depends on an abstraction that you can mock for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you view "retrieving RSS feeds from a url" and "consuming variants of RSS" as **two separate [responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**, you could just as easily reflect this in your code by creating separate components. 
That way **both components should be much easier to test in isolation** (i.e. just accepting input/output, no network traffic for the "consume" component).

If you are worried that this would break encapsulation, you might look into [dependency injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/07/DependencyInjectionisLooseCoupling/) as Mike suggested. If a component A requires some behavior B to work, to me at least it *should* be very obvious (for example, by asking it as a constructor argument) that it needs such a dependency rather than hiding it away in its implementation.